# Comparison between groups with one group normally distributed, and the other skewed

Tags: nonparametric, group-differences, skewness

I want to compare continuous numerical variables between two groups. Sample size is small (27 for one group and 43 for the other). I use Shapiro-Wilk test to check for normality of distribution of each variable in each subgroup. If distribution is normal in both groups, I just use a t-test. If distribution is not normal in both groups, I use a Mann-Whitney U test.

1) What do I do if it is normal in one group and abnormal in the other? Obviously there is a difference, but I want to say what the difference is, and then justify it with a p-value. I can't just say that the distributions are different. How do I find the difference in means? Do I compare the mean of the normal distribution with the median of the other? Do I compare the two medians?

2) If both are not normal, and I use a Mann-Whitney U test, how do I compare the medians if the result is significant? Again, the difference would be important to me, not only the fact that they would be from different distributions.

Transformations will not work for me because I have a lot of comparisons to make, and different variables require different transformations. Interpretation is hard already because of the nature of the variable, and having to interpret a back-transformed one will make it next to impossible I think.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you state your real problem, in the language of the application? Then maybe we can help.

Comment: My problem is not with the application itself, it's more two theoretical statistical questions. 

It is my understanding that a Mann-Whitney U tests the H0 that two groups have the same distribution. I don't only want to show that the two groups are different in respect to my variable of interest, I want to show by how much. In a t-test you do a comparison of means, and you say at the end the difference in means is x, and is significant because p<0.001. How do you define x in a Mann-Whitney U test? And how do you define it when one of the groups is normally distributed, and the other isn't?